# LWC not showing on App Page automatically

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, flexipages, lightning-app-builder

I have created 1 HelloWorld component and add it to a App Page, Now when I deploy it to another org as per below xml

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>helloWorld</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Hello_World</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

I cannot see the component in the App Page, I have tried deploying parallely and serially. Do I have to drag and drop the component on the App Page in Target org Explicitly.
If yes, Is there any documentation for the same. Can't we deploy the App Pages as is?
I see the retrieved file for Flexi Page as below, I don't see any `ItemInstances`

```
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Hello_World</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:defaultAppHomeTemplate</name>
    </template>
    <type>AppPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Why it is there?

Comment: Are you working in a Summer '21 org?

Comment: Yes I do, sourceApiversion is 51.0

Comment: What was the FlexiPage xml when you deployed (before you retrieved to check). There's this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001a1N4QAI&title=lwc-component-instances-are-dropped-from-flexipage-in-metadata-api-retrieve) that can drop LWC instances from FlexiPage in Summer '21 currently.

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact issue I am facing